# Define class in Delphi without implementation details

Tags: c++, delphi

My Delphi application using a C++ DLL which internally uses a 3rd party library (also written in C++). There is a class from the 3rd party library which I would like to use in the Delphi application. We have the header(s) from the 3rd party library.

The idea is to pass a pointer to an instance of this class, via CALLBACK, to the Delphi application. The object will only be used in Delphi, but never implemented there.

A cut down version of the C++ class is:

```
class XImage
{
public:
    XImage() {}
    ~XImage() {}

    inline uint32_t GetPixelVal(uint32_t row, uint32_t col) {...}

    uint32_t    _height;
    uint32_t    _width;
    uint32_t    _pixel_depth;
    uint8_t*    _data_;
};
```

I would like to define this class, as best I can, in Pascal:

```
TXImage = class
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy();

    DWORD GetPixelVal(DWORD row, DWORD col);

    DWORD   _height;
    DWORD   _width;
    DWORD   _pixel_depth;
    BYTE*   _data_;
  end;
```

But this results in compilation failure due to "Unsatisfied forward or external declaration".

Is there any way to define the interface to a class so that it is usable in Delphi, but without needing to provide implementation details?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Yes, I'd basically like to share an object, created in the C++ library, with the Delphi application. I'm just looking into Rudy's Delphi Corner (http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html) about using C++ objects in Delphi. Looks like I might need to write a wrapper to the object...

Comment: Use a COM interface

Comment: Yes, I think a COM interface is probably what I need. The Rudy Velthuis article suggested "flattening" the structure of the C++ class and exposing the methods as normal C functions with `extern "C"`.

Comment: The flattening option is much simpler and more portable (any C++ compiler will work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flattening approach [suggested by Rudy Velthuis](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html) worked, but I managed to solve the problem in a way which may be of interest to other Delphi developers. This approach works because the data that is needed (`_height`, `_width` and `_data_`) has been defined as public in the C++ class.

Step 1: Define a custom structure to hold the data from the C++ class.

```
// C++
typedef struct
{
    WORD width, height;
    BYTE* pBits;
} TXIMAGE, *PTXIMAGE;

// Delphi
PTXIMAGE = ^TXIMAGE;
TXIMAGE = record
    width, height: WORD;
    pBits: PBYTE;
end;
```

Step 2: Define a callback prototype to be used to communicate from C++ to Delphi.

```
// C++
typedef void (*CALLBACK_FRAME_READY)(PTXIMAGE);

// Delphi
TExternalProcCallback = procedure(image: PTXIMAGE); stdcall;
```

Step 3: Register the callback with the C++ DLL.

```
// Delphi
procedure RegisterCallbackFrameReady(callback: TExternalProcCallback); stdcall;
// ...
procedure RegisterCallbackFrameReady; external 'MyDLL.dll' name '_RegisterCallback@4'; stdcall;
// ...
RegisterCallbackFrameReady(SomeFunction);

// C++
void DETECTOR_COMMS_API RegisterCallback(CALLBACK_FRAME_READY pCallback)
{
    // Save this function pointer as member data...
    CALLBACK_FRAME_READY frameCallback = pCallback;
}
```

Step 4: Invoke the callback when your C++ object needs to be processed in Delphi.

```
// C++
TXIMAGE m_frame;
m_frame.width = static_cast<WORD>(image_->_width);
m_frame.height = static_cast<WORD>(image_->_height);
m_frame.pBits = image_->_data_;
if (frameCallback)
    frameCallback(&m_frame);
```

Step 5: Process the data in Delphi

```
procedure SomeFunction(image: PTXIMAGE); stdcall;
var
    Value, ValueMin, ValueMax: BYTE;
    x, y: WORD;
    pPixels: PBYTE;
begin
    // Detector frame!

    // Generate some frame diganostics
    Value := 0;
    ValueMin := High(WORD);
    ValueMax := Low(WORD);
    pPixels := image.pBits;
    for y:=0 to (image.height - 1) do
        begin
        for x:=0 to (image.width - 1) do
            begin
            Value := pPixels^;
            if (Value < ValueMin) then
                ValueMin := Value;

            if (Value > ValueMax) then
                ValueMax := Value;

            Inc(pPixels);
            end;
        end;
end;
```

Works nicely. As stated in the Rudy Velthuis article and in the comments, trying to export C++ classes is complex and can often be avoided.